# NSArray enumerateUsingBlock: can I access object at other index inside block?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

can I do this?

```
[array enumerateUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if (idx > 1)
    {
        NSUInteger previous1 = [array objectAtIndex: idx - 1].value;
        NSUInteger previous2 = [array objectAtIndex: idx - 2].value;
        obj.value = previous1 + previous2;
    }
}];
```

is it safe to do this? I am not adding/removing objects in array(or mutable array) inside enumeration block, I am just getting/changing value of object in other idx.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is OK, except that you have to cast your objects to the right type before you can use the dot syntax to get to the value property.

Comment: And the cast can be avoided if the block is declared with the actual type of the objects in the array: `^(MyType *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)`.

Comment: Then it still is needed for the results of `[array objectAtIndex:]`